# IO computation order

Tags: haskell

I have learned Haskell for some time, but IO monad yet scared me. 
I have a code

```
main = do
    putStrLn "First computation starts"
    let firstResult = foo -- foo is a pure function
    putStrLn "Second computation starts"
    let secondResult = bar foo -- bar is too pure function
    writeFile secondResult
```

And see `"First computation starts"` `"Second computation starts"` and then program will be doing.

I know that there is laisy computation, and really computation starts when `writeFile` executes.
I try to add strictness

```
    main = do
    putStrLn "First computation starts"
    let !firstResult = foo -- foo is a pure function
    putStrLn "Second computation starts"
    let !secondResult = bar foo -- bar is too pure function
    writeFile secondResult
```

Nothing happens

Well, maybe let expressions are only synonyms and exchanged by compiler? I try to turn functions into `IO`

```
main = do
putStrLn "First computation starts"
!firstResult <- return (foo) -- foo is a pure function
putStrLn "Second computation starts"
!secondResult <- return (bar foo) -- bar is too pure function
writeFile secondResult
```

Nevertheless, result is same as above, It's unclear for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure something has been evaluated, [deepseq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.3.0.1) is your friend. You will have to implement `NFData` for whatever `foo` is, but this is usually easy to do. Your `main` would then become

```
main = do
  putStrLn "First computation starts"
  firstResult <- return $!! foo
  putStrLn "Second computation starts"
  secondResult <- return $!! bar foo
  writeFile secondResult
```